# .hover and .click, different functions on same div, Jquery

Tags: jquery, click, hide, toggle

I want to Show "1" when hovering "Toggle 1", and show "2" when I click "Toggle 1". 
I also want to create a rule, where "Toggle 2" would show "3" on hover and "4" on click.
I put the closing div for "hover (toggle 1) behind "front (2)" to be able to click 2 to toggle as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hover">Toggle 1
<div class="front" style="display:none">2</div></div>
<div class="back" style="display:none">1</div>

<div class="hover">Toggle 2
<div class="front" style="display:none">4</div></div>
<div class="back" style="display:none">3</div>

<script>

$("div.hover").click(function () {
$("div.front").toggle( );
});

$("div.hover").hover(
function() { $(this).children("div.back").show(); },
function() { $(this).children("div.back").hide(); }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$.on()`, not `$.click/hover/change/live()`, etc.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't make any sense.

```
$("div.hover").hover(
function() { $(this).children("div.back").show(); },
function() { $(this).children("div.back").hide(); }
});
```

What are you trying? Hiding and showing at the same time?

Greg B. is right, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Try this code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hover">Toggle 1
<div class="front" style="display:none">2</div>
<div class="back" style="display:none">1</div>
</div>
<div class="hover">Toggle 2
<div class="front" style="display:none">4</div>
<div class="back" style="display:none">3</div>
</div>
<script>


hoverdiv = $("div.hover")

hoverdiv.on("hover", function() {
    $(this).children(".front").show()
});
hoverdiv.on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).children(".front").hide()
})
hoverdiv.on("click", function() {
    $(this).children(".back").toggle()
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this is the solution im looking for.

Comment: I have a problem here. Now the action is no longer limited to one of them, but all actions happen on Toggle1 and Toggle2 simultaneously.

Comment: You could replace `hoverdiv = $("div.hover")` with `hoverdiv = $("div.hover:first")`.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. But now only Toggle 1 is a trigger. Maybe I was bad at explaining. I want hover on Toggle1 to show "1" and on click show "2". On "Toggle2" I want to show 3 on hover and 4 on click.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code. Notice that now the position of the closing div tags have changed.

Answer (score 4):

Your closing div are in the wrong spot and it's screwing it up I think.

```
<div class="hover">Toggle 1
  <div class="front" style="display:none">2</div>
  <div class="back" style="display:none">1</div>
</div>

<div class="hover">Toggle 2
  <div class="front" style="display:none">4</div>
  <div class="back" style="display:none">3</div>
</div>
```

Try that.